# Database Backend for my app

Tags: database, parse-platform, backend

I am developing a small app. I used a database Parse.com to authenticate users and to push. As Parse.com closed in a year, I want to switch to another platform. What do you recomend me?

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found NodeChef https://nodechef.com/parse-server to be the easiest so far. It's fully managed just like the parse.com service. It is also powered
by Parse Server. That means you don't have to rewrite your app.

Answer (score 0):

There is a list of Parse alternatives - and there are many - along with some discussion about each over here.

https://github.com/relatedcode/ParseAlternatives